# To make ordered list and style each li as a box

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I want to make an ordered list and style each li as a box. Like this:

[image: ordered list having each li as a box]

I tried this:

```css
.box{

  box-sizing: border-box;

  width: 100%;

  font-weight: bold;

  color: black;

  background-color: #ffffff;

  padding: 10px 12px;

  border-radius: 10px;

  box-shadow: rgba(17, 17, 26, 0.05) 0px 1px 0px, rgba(17, 17, 26, 0.1) 0px 0px 8px;

}

li{

background-color:lightblue;

margin-bottom:  10px;

border-radius: 5px;

}
```

```html
<div class="box">

<h3>What is your name?</h3>

 <ol class="a">
   <li>apple</li>
   <li>ball</li>
   <li>cat</li>
   <li>dog</li></ol>
</div>
```

But, it doesn't look exactly as I want to make it. This is what I got when I tried:

[image: Ordered list each li as abox]

Comment: a list item is a block element by default. SO it is visual as a box anyways. Do you mean not to be indented?

Comment: `list-style-position: inside; padding:5px;` will do the trick